# Как указать COLLATE для столбца таблицы?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Имеется проект EF6 (code-First). В сущности File имеется свойство FullPath, содержащее полный путь к файлу в верхнем регистре. 
Проблема в том, что при поиске файла содержащего в своем пути символ `ß` он прозрачно меняется на `ss`, другими словами возвращается не то что ищем:

```sql
SELECT FullPath 
FROM File
WHERE FullPath = '\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER\STOß.TXT'
--      returns: '\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER\STOSS.TXT'
```

Поэтому, при наличии путей отличающихся написанием `ß` и 'ss' происходят ошибки.

Можно ли каким-либо образом установить COLLATE для определенного столбца? Каким образом решается эта проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A-K [предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/667808/182750) вариант установки COLLATE с помощью миграций. В конкретном случае я выбрал другой вариант, т.к. миграции не так уж и редко удаляются при разработке. Вполне возможно мной не учитываются какие-либо подводные камни, в этом случае укажите на это в комментариях.

Для начала необходимо создать класс реализующий интерфейс [IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323(v=vs.113).aspx). Ниже приведен пример наследования от [CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679221(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
public class DbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<CustomContext> {

    void SetCollation(DbContext ctx, 
                      string table, 
                      string col, 
                      string colType,
                      string collation, 
                      bool isNullable = false) {

        string connStr = ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
        string nullStr = isNullable ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL";
        string sqlCmd = $"ALTER TABLE dbo.[{table}] ALTER COLUMN [{col}] {colType} COLLATE {collation} {nullStr}";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr)) {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, connection)) {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    protected override void Seed(CustomContext ctx) {

        string collation = "Latin1_General_100_BIN";
        SetCollation(ctx, {nameof(DbSetOne)}, {nameof(DbSetOne.ColName)}, "NVARCHAR(500)", collation);
        SetCollation(ctx, {nameof(DbSetTwo)}, {nameof(DbSetTwo.OtherColName)}, "NVARCHAR(250)", collation, true);
    }
}
```

Здесь интересен переопределяемый метод [Seed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt136533(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists%601.Seed(%600)). Этом метод будет вызван при инициализации БД. Таким образом можно выполнять какие-либо начальные действия, к примеру заполнять БД данными по-умолчанию. Затем в конструкторе класса контекста можно указать свой инициализатор базы данных с помощью [Database.SetInitializer<TContext>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
public partial class CustomContext : DbContext {
    public CustomContext() : base("name=CustomContext") {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DbInitializer());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ограниченность подхода в том, что вы разрабатываете под себя и позволяете стирать любые миграции и удалять базу. Когда вы будете работать в команде, когда у вас разные версии приложения будут установлены по паре сотен клиентов... будет очень больно отвыкать от такой халявы, как дропанье базы. Но если сейчас вам решение подходит -- то ставьте галку и пользуйтесь, просто учтите на будущее.

Comment: @AK Но приведенный пример никоим образом не связан с миграциями. База данных создается один раз и инициализатор будет выполнен один раз. Помимо этого, работает как с миграциями, так и без таковых. Как бы то ни было - спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 1):

Из коробки [EF не поддерживает COLLATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285781/entity-framework-code-first-change-table-column-collation).

Если вы хотите указать -- тогда в поправьте метод Up() миграции, создающей столбец SQL-запрос с ALTER COLUMN, как-то так:

```
public partial class DisplayNameInUser : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        this.AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "DisplayName", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 70));
        this.Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.AspNetUsers ALTER COLUMN DisplayName nvarchar(70) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS");
        this.Sql("UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers SET DisplayName = UserName");
        this.CreateIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "DisplayName", unique: true, name: "DisplayNameIndex");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        this.DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "DisplayNameIndex");
        this.DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "DisplayName");
    }
}
```

Насчёт того, какую кодировку ставить мммм.... я бы рекомендовал поэкспериментировать самостоятельно, в помощь могу посоветовать этот топик на EnSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871959

Возможно, вам подойдёт SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2, проверил только что на SQL 11:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
([Id] , [Email],[EmailConfirmed],[PasswordHash],[SecurityStamp],[PhoneNumber],[PhoneNumberConfirmed],[TwoFactorEnabled],[LockoutEndDateUtc],[LockoutEnabled],[AccessFailedCount],[UserName],[DisplayName])
VALUES
('1', 'mail1@gmail.com', 0, '123','123',null, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 'Masse', 'Masse')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
([Id] , [Email],[EmailConfirmed],[PasswordHash],[SecurityStamp],[PhoneNumber],[PhoneNumberConfirmed],[TwoFactorEnabled],[LockoutEndDateUtc],[LockoutEnabled],[AccessFailedCount],[UserName],[DisplayName])
VALUES
('2', 'mail2@gmail.com', 0, '123','123',null, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 'Maße', 'Maße')

SELECT TOP 10 
* 
FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] 
WHERE 1 = 1
-- AND DisplayName like '%ss%'
AND DisplayName like '%ß%'
```

Comment: спасибо большое, но решилось немного по-другому.